# Run cron with frequency more than once a minute

Tags: php, shell, cron

This is the content of fastcron.php, and I am trying to speed up the frequency to once per 10 seconds rather than the default once per minute.

```
<?php

system("(sleep 10 && php -f /home/thanksfo/public_html/_aweber/admin/cron/cron.php) &
(sleep 20 && php -f /home/big/public_html/_aweber/admin/cron/cron.php) &
(sleep 30 && php -f /home/big/public_html/_aweber/admin/cron/cron.php) &
(sleep 40 && php -f /home/big/public_html/_aweber/admin/cron/cron.php) &
(sleep 50 && php -f /home/big/public_html/_aweber/admin/cron/cron.php) &
(sleep 60 && php -f /home/big/public_html/_aweber/admin/cron/cron.php) &");

?>
```

Is the code correct and how do I make sure my system won't crash if i run this? Am on a VPS.

Comment: Is there any good reason to execute a cron script so often?

Comment: https://github.com/erlware/erlcron

Comment: @Hast: Yes, the current setting is too slow.

Comment: what  you have posted doesn't make any sense in the context of "cron with frequency of more than once a minute". Why all of the sleeps,? and '&&'s? AND all the '&' (run in the background) all to run the same script??? Why would need to start this up more than once in 5 minutes, let alone 1 minute? You'll do better to step back and reframe your question as a statement of your ultimate need, rather than adding another (apparent) bandaid to a solution that seems very likely to have unintended consequences. Good luck.